# After update Eclipse I can not generate reports in JasperStudio

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have little problem. In previous version of Eclipse (2019-06) I created many reports with JasperSoft (plug-in in eclipse). Yesterday I updated to new version (big mistake?) and I can not create reports. I do everything as always and this is my result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport.createCell(TableReport.java:1600)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.createColumnCell(TableReport.java:497)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ColumnHeaderCreator.createColumnCell(TableReport.java:709)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ColumnHeaderCreator.createColumnCell(TableReport.java:686)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.visitColumn(TableReport.java:476)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.visitColumn(TableReport.java:442)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.StandardColumn.visitColumn(StandardColumn.java:74)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.visit(TableReport.java:555)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport.createColumnHeader(TableReport.java:1112)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport.<init>(TableReport.java:300)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.createFillTableSubreportFactory(FillTable.java:335)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.createFillSubreport(FillTable.java:309)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.evaluate(FillTable.java:131)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.evaluate(JRFillComponentElement.java:110)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2022)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:121)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:583)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:929)
at com.baeldung.jasperreports.Main.main(Main.java:242)
```

This is my code (shorter version):

```
String outputFile = File.separatorChar + "D:\\eclipse\\JasperTableExample2.pdf";

Collection<Person> osoba = new ArrayList<Person>();

Person john = new Person();
john.setName("John");
john.setSurname("Doe");
john.setEmail("john@gmail.com");
john.setAge(22);
john.setX(5);
john.setY(5);
john.setZ(1);
john.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.of(2019,12,12,9,25));
osoba.add(john);

JRBeanCollectionDataSource personJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(osoba);
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("ItemDataSource", personJRBean);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D://path//NewReport.jasper", parameters, new JREmptyDataSource()); // this is #242 line at Main.java
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile));
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
```

I do not put here a Person class. Java code works well.

In JasperStudio I create new report, new parameter (name as in code - ItemDataSource, set class to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource`). Then I create a table with the new dataset and choose this:

[image]

Then I just launched Main and the report was generated.

Before update, this process worked perfectly, but after "update step" I am getting this error.

Comment: And sorry, mistake 
`at com.baeldung.jasperreports.Main.main(Main.java:242)` 

is this line 

`JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D://eclipse//Eclipse_Workspace//tutorials-master//libraries-2//src//main//resources//com//NewReport.jasper", parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());`

Comment: Did you try to debug what caused the NPE?

Comment: No, I did not. I will try tomorrow. But as I said - before update everything was fine. The charts work, but I can not do the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with the same stacktrace.
It was not about eclipse but about the Jaspersoft Studio version.

I was using Jaspersoft Studio 6.11.0 in eclipse and version 6.4.3 of jasperreports.jar at runtime.
I had to upgrade my pom.xml (I'm using maven) to both 6.11.0 and it fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! Mistake was between computer and chair. :-)